# How can I used array to have arbitrary type of elements?

Tags: c, pointers, buffer

I know this would not work, because I cannot make arithmetic on void:

```
int main (void) {

   void *ar = malloc(25); //adress of int + adr of char + adr of int = 3 * 8 + 1 null
   int a =4;
   int b =6;
   *(ar+0)=&a //adr of first int - 8 bytes
   *(ar+8)="abc\0"; // adr of the first char - 8 bytes
   *(ar+16)=&b; // adr of the second int - 8 bytes
   ar[24] = NULL;

   return 0;
}
```

So the question is , how to make an buffer with arbitrary type, only according to its byte width (specifically the buffer in this case would contains 3 addresses of arbitrary types, but that should not matter, since all addresses are 8 bytes long)?

How how to enable to compiler to do arithmetic on `(void*)`, according to programmers intend? (because I specify how long of the buffer I want to move forward to reach the first byte to start at).

Comment: To do address arithmetic in units of bytes, use a pointer to `unsigned char`. To put data in the calculated locations, copy the bytes of the data into them with `memcpy` or with individual assignments of bytes (`unsigned char`). (Also note that only 24 bytes were allocated, so `ar[24]` would be beyond the reserved space. It should not be written to, as `as[24] = NULL;` attempts.)

Answer (score 0):

Specify the type as a pointer to a pointer to void (or as an array of pointers). The compiler knows the size of a pointer to void, allowing you to perform arithmetic as per usual.

**On the stack:**

`void *arr[3];`

**Dynamically:**

`void **arr = malloc(sizeof(void*)*3);`

**Usage:**

```
int a = 10, b = 20, c = 30;
arr[0] = &a;
arr[1] = &b;
arr[2] = &c;
```